# How to return true or false if my current datacenter is in the ENUM?

Tags: java, enums

I am working on a project in which I need to return true if my current datacenter is either DC1, DC2 or DC3 only not DEV by looking at the enum as mentioned below. And if is not then return false.

With the use of Below code, I can find my machine name. And my machine name looks like this -

```
tps1143.dc1.host.com
tps1142.dc2.host.com
tps1442.dc3.host.com
```

Below is my code -

```
public enum DatacenterEnum {
    DEV, DC1, DC2, DC3;

    public static String forCode(int code) {
        return (code >= 0 && code < values().length) ? values()[code].name() : null;
    }

    private static final String getHostName() {
    try {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName().toLowerCase();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // log error
    }

    return null;
    }
}
```

Below is my main method -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(DatacenterEnum.getHostName());
}
```

How do I go ahead and solve this problem?

Basically I just need to return true or false if where my code is running is in datacenter DC1 or DC2 or DC3. My machine name contains Datacenter information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joshua Bloch has mentioned an interesting use case scenario for `EnumSet` in Item 32 of his Java Classic [Effective Java](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf) . This item advises us to use `EnumSet` in the place of bit fields, which is part of *enum int pattern*. In *enum int pattern*, different `enum` constants are represented as power of 2 and later combined using bitwise operators.

So as Puce has said in his answer you can use it like :

```
private static final Set<DatacenterEnum> DC_DATACENTERS = EnumSet.of(DC1, DC2, DC3);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you want to do with all these static methods in the Enum, but regarding the asked issue, have a look at [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) and its `contains` method.

E.g.:

```
private static final Set<DatacenterEnum> DC_DATACENTERS = EnumSet.of(DC1, DC2, DC3);

public static boolean isDcDatacenter(DatacenterEnum datacenter){
    return DC_DATACENTERS.contains(datacenter);
}

...


if (DatacenterEnum.isDcDatacenter(someDatacenter)){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By checking which enum you are passed (in `yourEnumInstance`) and returning a value based on it

```
switch (yourEnumInstance)
{
 case DC1:
 case DC2:
 case DC3:
  return true;

 case DEV:
 default:
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, `return yourEnumInstance != DEV;` would do the same…

Comment: You could also add methods to the enum or do a `contains` but I find this is the easiest to read and adapt

Answer (score 0):

```
String machineName = "tps1143.dc1.host.com"; // example
DatacenterEnum.valueOf(machineName.split("\\.")[1].toUpperCase()) != DataCenterEnum.DEV
```